# running @Test one by one using reflection

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I’m trying to run a package with many unit tests (one by one, not as a class) using reflection,
So when I get all the @Test methods that needs to be run I try to do

```
Result result = new JUnitCore().run(Request.method(Class
                                .forName(packageAndClass),getTestName()));
```

But the class returned in packageAndClass has
@Before, @BeforeClass methods (that also might be in its superclass)

So when running the code above I get all the tests running and fail(because some of their values are assigned in the @Before and @BeforeClass methods)
But when running it from eclipse (select the test method name -> right click -> run as -> Junit test)
They all pass (runing together or one by one)
Is there an api of Request that will run the before methods?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing that? JUnit is supposed to run the tests for you!

Comment: +1 There is no point in reinventing something which is used by worldwide community.

Comment: i write a tool that uses junitCore (junit api)
i can't run it from eclipse because the tool is GUIless

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following test with junit 4.9 :

```
public class RunOneTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Result result = new JUnitCore().run(Request.method(RunOneTest.class, "oneTest"));
        System.out.println("result " + result.wasSuccessful());
    }

    @Test
    public void oneTest() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("oneTest");
    }

    @Test
    public void anotherTest() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("anotherTest");
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("before");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("beforeClass");
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        System.out.println("after");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        System.out.println("afterClass");
    }
}
```

and the output was :

```
beforeClass
before
oneTest
after
afterClass
result true
```

Are you really sure that the methods are not run ?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the effort! i'm sure because the @before actions were not run on my env. i'll try to reproduce it with 4.9.

Comment: @Itaik you are welcome. If you still have the problem, you should provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org).